# What is the difference between \ifmmode and \textormath?

Tags: math-mode, macros

Inspecting code of a package I saw the following two lines:

```
\def\th{\textormath{\text@th}{\math@th}}
```

and

```
\ifmmode{\nfss@text{\textnumero}}\else\textnumero\fi}
```

I guess that `textormath` and `\ifmmode` do basically the same: they print either their first or their second argument depending on whether math or text mode is active. But what is the difference between these two commands? And which one is preferable?

Comment: you have an unmatched `}` in your `\ifmmode` example, note that it doesn't take brace arguments but `\ifmmode yes \else no \fi`

Comment: Neither is good; the first redefines a LaTeX kernel command (defined in `t1enc.def`), whereas the second may work wrongly in `array` (it should have `\relax\ifmmode`).

Answer (score 9):

The latex format defines `\TextorMath` which is a very thin wrapper around `\ifmmode`  You don't say what defined `\textormath` but it is presumably similar.

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname protected\endcsname\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand\TextOrMath{%
  \ifmmode  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else     \expandafter\@firstoftwo  \fi}
\protected@edef\TextOrMath#1#2{\TextOrMath{#1}{#2}}
\else
\protected\expandafter\def\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname{%
  \ifmmode  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else     \expandafter\@firstoftwo  \fi}
\edef\TextOrMath#1#2{%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}
\fi
```

In general it's better to use the latex form unless you know the context and it it is safe to use the TeX primitive, notably in section headings and at the start of table cells `\ifmmode` acts in a well defined way but not as you may expect and not usefully, (it is always false at the start of an array cell for example)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



$
\begin{array}{c}
  \ifmmode math \else text\fi \\
  {}\ifmmode math \else text\fi \\
  \TextOrMath{text}{math} \\
  {}\TextOrMath{text}{math} \\
\end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The (lowercase) macro `\textormath` is defined in `babel.def` and provides a wrapper to the `\ifmmode` macro:

```
\def\textormath{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
```

As such, it will have the same problems as a direct use of `\ifmmode` e.g. at the beginning of a cell (see David's answer).

Comment: I upvoted anyway:-) hmm babel should probably at least stick a `\relax` in there,

Comment: Apparently, `\TextOrMath` was added to LaTeX in 2005, first as part of the `fixltx2e` package (see `ltnews.pdf`, issue 17). I think it's possible that babel's `\textormath` command predates that. You might argue that these days, they should just `\let\textormath=\TextOrMath`.